# How to send order confirmation email from back end in prestashop 1.6.3

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to send  order confirmation email from back end manually in prestashop 1.6.3
I have  option  in back end for sending email for payment acceptance ,But how to send email and invoice attachment  again manually from back end  .
The option for payement acceptance is default but is there option to send rder confirmation again if not how to do this?

[image]

Suppose my customer calls and says  he didnt reciveor he deleted all the mails so he coud not find that mail ,can you send me back again the same mail , for this purpose I need this manual functionality in the band end cms

Answer (score 0):

If you open /classes/PaymentModule.php - validateOrder() function

You will find the following code

```
Mail::Send(
                            (int)$order->id_lang,
                            'order_conf',
                            Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
                            $data,
                            $this->context->customer->email,
                            $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
                            null,
                            null,
                            $file_attachement,
                            null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
                        );
```

This code is responsible for sending the order confirmation email, you can reuse the code from the admin panel but you have to supply all the parameters manually.